# For a duplicate question, mark an answer from original question as accepted

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question that turned out to be a duplicate. It got two responses, neither of which I found particularly insightful, however when it was marked as a duplicate I checked the answers on the original question, and one of them solved my problem.

Is there a way for me to accept this answer from an older question, or at least refer other users who comes across my question that I found the answers in the duplicate to work for me? I want to make the question as answered, but none of the direct answers to my question are it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always a good idea to upvote an answer that helped you, regardless of whether it's an answer to your question or someone else's .

The idea with questions being marked as duplicates is to keep all useful content regarding a problem and its solution in one thread and direct the prying eyes of future generations to that thread.

Ideally, **your** question will never be seen, and the original question (with the answer that was useful to you) will be the one returned by search engines the next time someone has the problem.

Comment: _"Ideally, your question will never be seen"_ Or more accurately, _will_ be seen point to the main question and the right answers. Search engines won't hide the question just because it's closed, after all, and we close as a duplicate not to _keep the question from being found_ but instead so when it _is_ found, it's a sign post to the solution.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I knew this. I was just hoping there was a way I could specificically indicate which answer in the original helped me without having editing my question and throwing a explanation in the end of it.

Comment: @AlphaBetaParkingLot, yeah, I don't think there is any more explicit mechanism baked in, unfortunately. Going along with Kendra's point about your question being a "signpost," editing in a link to the useful answer would probably be a nice courtesy.

Comment: @AlphaBetaParkingLot Actually, I wouldn't edit the link into your question- It's not _part_ of your question and is liable to be (correctly) edited out as noise. You _could_ however post a comment pointing to the useful answer, if you wanted to.